# PWA support in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

we would like to build a fully offline capable react web application. We usually work with NextJS.

The current problem that we are facing is that we are not able to precache all routes of the application, even though they are not making use of SSR.

For example:

```
pages
 - index.js
 - projects
   - index.js
   - [id.js]
```

The service worker should precache all pages (HTML) upfront, so that the application is immediately fully offline capable:

- /
- /projects
- /projects/123
- /projects/???

We tried to use [next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) and [next-pwa](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa), but we were only able to precache the static assets.

Has anybody had a similar requirement and found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2022 May

There is an open enhancement request for `next-pwa` to enable precaching all pages: [**How to precache ALL pages**](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/issues/252)

### Workaround

Sylvie Fiquet found a workaround to enable caching all pages with `next-pwa` and wrote a blog post: [**Precaching pages with next-pwa**](https://dev.to/sfiquet/precaching-pages-with-next-pwa-31f2)

The short version of the solution follows.

- Decide which HTML and JSON files to precache

  - if you use standard `<a>` links: precache HTML files only
  - if you use `<Link>` client-side navigation: precache JSON files and at minimum the HTML file for the start URL. Decide whether to precache all HTML files or just have a fallback page.
- Generate the build ID yourself (e.g. with nanoid or uuid) and pass it to the Next.js build via `generateBuildId`
- Generate the list of entries to precache and pass it to next-pwa via `pwa.additionalManifestEntries`

  - Use the build ID as the `revision` for HTML entries
  - Include the build ID in the URL for JSON entries with `revision` set to null
  - If you want to precache the content of the `public` folder, you have to do it yourself
- To precache the home page HTML: set `pwa.dynamicStartUrl` to `false` (default `true` puts it in the runtime cache instead). Note that this doesn't precache the JSON.
- Implement as a config function to avoid running your build functions for every single Next.js command

### Example for build id `OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1`

##### URLs:

| HTML | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| / | /_next/data/OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1/index.json |
| /about | /_next/data/OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1/about.json |
| /posts/myfirstpost | /_next/data/OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1/posts/myfirstpost.json |

#### `ManifestEntry` objects for `/posts/myfirstpost`:

##### HTML:

```
{
  url: '/posts/myfirstpost',
  revision: 'OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1',
}
```

##### JSON:

```json
{
  url: '/_next/data/OUEmUvoIwu1Azj0i9Vad1/posts/myfirstpost.json',
  revision: null,
}
```

**Caveat**: There is potential for trouble if you precache too many pages. Keep an eye on the size of your cache. Remember that a single JS file for a dynamic page could translate into thousands of pages, depending on what happens in `getStaticPaths`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make you custom service worker or simply use the package
https://github.com/hanford/next-offline with the easy configuration for PWA offline support
[image]

Edit: Attached Screenshot for external script

Comment: The problem is that this package is not precaching all routes with it's corresponding HTML files. Static assets are working fine.

Comment: it accepts   workboxOpts options so you can customize according to your need
Read here for more options 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generatesw_plugin

Comment: @RajatDhoot
Helllo, do you know where exactly in nextjs project, do I import the service worker file for it to work?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK in nextjs config need to add script path. Screenshot attached above

Comment: @RajatDhoot Thoughts on just using Workbox for Nextjs? Any  experience on that?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK workbox can be easily configured with next-offline kindly check docs it's easy to configure
https://github.com/hanford/next-offline

Comment: @RajatDhoot Yes, but I wanted to try without next-offline
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841653/nextjs-and-workbox-integration
Feel free to answer if you know the answer

Comment: Are you using next server or custom server...?

Comment: @RajatDhoot NextJS server.