# Nextjs and workbox integration

Tags: next.js, workbox

**Requirement**: I am trying to use service worker and cache static files so as to have a benefit to reduce HTTP requests and make the site performance better. 
Down the lane I would switch to offline, caching images, api's etc.

I have seen the plugins:

https://github.com/hanford/next-offline and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa

It seems to work. Although I was trying to find out if there were examples of **(nextjs + workbox)**.

Next js do have an example for https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-next-offline. But I would like just using workbox for this.

Anyone got any working examples? Even a basic one would do.

Currently am not using a custom server. Just using the inbuilt builder of nextjs (https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#manual-setup)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer on my own:

Reference: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.generateSW
I have done runtime caching for my app here and added the workbox file into the base file:

```
 // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const serviceWorkerScope = `/${country}/workbox-worker.js`
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register(serviceWorkerScope)
          .then(() => {
            logger.info(`Service worker registered at ${serviceWorkerScope}`)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            logger.error("Error in serviceWorker registration: ", error)
          })
      })
})
```

```
I have added comments,

    // File to generate the service worker.
    require("dotenv").config()
    const workboxBuild = require("workbox-build")
    const { COUNTRY: country, NODE_ENV } = process.env
    const urlPattern = new RegExp(`/${country}\/static|_next\/.*/`)
    
    // https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.generateSW
    const buildSW = () => {
      return workboxBuild.generateSW({
        swDest: "public/workbox-worker.js",
        clientsClaim: true,
        mode: NODE_ENV,
        skipWaiting: true,
        sourcemap: false,
        runtimeCaching: [
          {
            urlPattern: urlPattern,
    
            // Apply a cache-first strategy.
            handler: "CacheFirst",
            options: {
              cacheName: "Static files caching",
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 50,
                maxAgeSeconds: 15 * 60, // 15minutes
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    }
    
    buildSW()
```

Comment: Going through a similar issue right now. Thank you for posting clear explanations on all of this, it helped a lot.

Comment: No worries,I had gone through a bit of trouble myself. I can understand. @EricCrescioni